# perform backup of particular number of rows in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL, and I use SQL Server 2008 as my back end to store student attendance details. In a day nearly 10,000 records are stored. I learned the query for taking a backup:

```
backup database dbname to disk =E:\\sqlbackup.bak with init,stats=10
```

and restore:

```
USE master ALTER DATABASE dbname 
SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate 
RESTORE DATABASE dbname FROM DISK =E:\\sqlbackup.bak WITH RECOVERY, 
REPLACE ALTER DATABASE dbname SET Multi_User
```

What I want to do is, after every semester is over, I want to take a backup of the last semester records and then truncate them from the table (for efficiency purposes) so that in case the admin wants to check the last semester attendance of a student, they can restore it from the backup and check (which should ensure the current data are also not overwritten).

How can I perform this? I read articles about partial backup, but I don't have a clear idea.

Comment: SQL Server backup doesn't support backing up only parts of the database based on your data.

Comment: thank you for your immediate reply @marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply create a backup of the current database at the end of your semenster with appropriate meaningful name and then truncate the existing database.
If there is only specific data you want then you could simply attach the backup under a different name and delete the data you do not want.
or you could create an empty database, export the data you want to keep, and then detach it.